# Loop every skill and not only few of them

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml, api-eveonline

I'm trying to loop every skill that can be found in EVE Online ([API Skilltree](https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx)) but the following code only loop through the first 7 skill groups.

```
$skilltree_url = file_get_contents('https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx', 0, null, null);
$skilltree = simplexml_load_string($skilltree_url);

foreach($skilltree->result->rowset->row AS $skill) {
    var_dump($skill->rowset->row->attributes()->typeID);
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx');
$skilltree = $xml->result->rowset;
foreach($skilltree->row as $skill) {
    var_dump($skill->rowset->row->attributes()->typeID);
}
```

Prints this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '2403' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3184' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3300' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3319' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3327' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3348' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3355' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3363' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3380' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3392' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3402' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3413' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3426' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3436' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3443' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3449' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3551' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3731' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '3755' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '3893' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '4385' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '4411' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '9955' (length=4)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '11015' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '11075' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '11082' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '11204' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '11207' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '11208' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '11395' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '11433' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '11566' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '11569' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '11579' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '11584' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '11858' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '12092' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '12179' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '12180' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '12201' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '12241' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '12305' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '12365' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '12368' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '12441' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '12484' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '12834' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '13278' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '13279' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '16069' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '16281' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '16591' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '16594' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '17940' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '18025' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '18580' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '19430' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '19759' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '20127' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '20209' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '20327' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '20342' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '20433' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '20494' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '20524' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '21059' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '21071' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '21603' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '21610' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '21666' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '21668' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '21718' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '21802' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '21803' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '22043' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '22172' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '22242' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '22536' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '22541' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '22551' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '22552' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '22578' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '22761' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '22806' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '23069' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '23087' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '23566' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '23950' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '24241' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '24242' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '24268' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '24270' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '24311' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '24562' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '24568' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '24571' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '24606' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '24613' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '24624' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '24625' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '24764' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '25233' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '25530' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '25544' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '25718' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '25739' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '25863' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '26224' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '26252' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '27911' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '27936' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '28073' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '28164' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '28261' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '28373' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '28374' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '28585' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '28604' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '28609' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '28631' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '28656' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '28879' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '29029' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '30324' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '30532' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '30650' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '30788' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '32339' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '32435' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '32797' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '32856' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[6]
  string '32918' (length=5)
object(SimpleXMLElement)[7]
  string '32999' (length=5)
```

Comment: If you var_dump the whole array (on parent index) first, what do you get?

Comment: Seems to work fine here, getting all the top groups and the their first typeID. Got anymore things you're using to run this?

Comment: Try running this
`<?php
$skilltree_url = file_get_contents('https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx', 0, null, null);
$skilltree = simplexml_load_string($skilltree_url);




foreach($skilltree->result->rowset->row AS $skill) {
    var_dump($skill->attributes()->groupName);
}`
this results in all the group name for me.

Comment: I'm getting this if I move out the `var_dump()` from the foreach loop: `object(SimpleXMLElement)[9] string '2403' (length=4)`

Comment: CE_REAL: I want to get all of the skill groups. Not the first 7 groups which I'm getting with that code. I want to reach out for the `TypeID` for every skill that are in these skill groups

Comment: @ErikEdgren what PHP version are you using, it seems to me that your loop isn't working correctly, because you're only getting the first typeID, when I put the var_dump outside of the loop (after the loop is finished) I get the last typeID that's found in the xml.

Comment: Hm. Weird. If I do so too, I'm only getting the first 7 skill groups as I said :P :S I have PHP v5.3.8 according to `phpinfo()`

Comment: But with your code that you gave me, I'm getting all of the skill groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, and is a bit easier to use:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx');
$skilltree = $xml->result->rowset;
foreach($skilltree->row as $skill) {
    var_dump($skill->rowset->row->attributes()->typeID);
}
```

Edit:

This should be the whole thing you need, rest of the attributes you should be able to figure out by yourself:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://api.eveonline.com/eve/SkillTree.xml.aspx');
$skilltree = $xml->result->rowset;
foreach($skilltree->row as $skillgroup) {
    echo 'Group name: ' .$skillgroup->attributes()->groupName .'<br />';
    foreach ($skillgroup->rowset->row as $skill) {
        echo 'Type ID: ' .$skill->attributes()->typeID .'<br />';
        echo 'Type name: ' .$skill->attributes()->typeName .'<br />';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) But it doesn't prints every skill that are in the skill groups. Please see my edit in my question. But I'm questing that you have chosen to only print out the skill groups ID.

Comment: @ErikEdgren check my update, should be what you need. Mark the answer as accepted if this is what you need.

Comment: Sweet! :D So I had to have 2 `foreach` loops to accomplish this. Many thanks :D

Comment: Yes, because of the many skill groups, which each have a couple of skills, makes many + many which results in a foreach for both, at least that's that's as far as I know the easiest.
Glad that I could have helped.

Comment: Very true :) Their XML page isn't that small. Many thanks once again :)